# Waveshare USB3300 board with stm32f429

Tags: usb, stm32f4

I am trying to hook up the  [Waveshare USB3300](http://www.wvshare.com/product/USB3300-USB-HS-Board.htm) to a stm32f429 discovery board. I have been having an issue getting it to work. It has two pins that specify 5V and two pins that specify 3V. I am not sure if both are needed or just one.

When i try to hookup the 3V (with or without the 5v connected) the stm32f429 dicovery board shuts down. When i connect just the 5v stm32f429 board stays on. Usb3300 ground pins terminated to stm32f429 ground. I would like to connect usb3300 via usb mini to pc for serial transfer. The logic pins are pretty easy, but the power requirements for the board have me a little confused. Does anybody have experience using this USB3300 waveshare board. Are both 3v and 5v required? Or just one or the other?

Thanks

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: They only had datasheets for chips on the board. It certainly would have been nice if they had one for the board, pretty sad. They did post schematic though http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/File:USB3300-USB-HS-Board-Schematic.pdf. Based on my limited electrical skills i would say the board needs 3v. I thought that perhaps it needed more power than what stm could deliver so i hooked up 3v supply with 650ma output. Only to see the power led fluctuate on and off a few times before i disconnected. I think this board is defective.

Comment: @NickJohnson answer is correct, the board needs both. Don't like the implementation, though. It departs from datasheet recommendations in several places, e.g pins 15 and 26 are not connected, even though this specifically mentioned in datasheet in two places. Re STM shutting down - double check STM pin configurations for all the pins connected to ULPI

Comment: Also 3.0V is a low minimum for VDD per datasheet, I'd recommend using 3.3V supply

Comment: This device has some unforgivable flaws. Misses packets on bus, no documentation on protocol, zero support under Linux. Stray bytes between packets on communication with PC. It is unusable.

Answer (score 2):

The schematic you linked shows that the USB3300 expects a 3v supply for its onboard electronics (and 3v level signalling for its IO pins), and a 5v supply for the USB port, which is controlled by a load switch. For proper functionality connecting to a USB device, you need to connect a 3v supply with enough power for the onboard electronics, and a 5v supply with enough power for whatever USB device you attach.